# facebook connect fails on IE9 when a port is used

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

My facebook Website app is configured for a site url using a port number

ie  www.example.com:900

Fconnect functionality works in Firefox (all versions) however ie9 gives an error stating

"An error occurred with xxxAppname. Please try again later."

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An example of the code that you're using would be helpful.  Have you checked all of the Application information on the Facebook Developer website to ensure that the URL matches EXACTLY.  http://www.website.com is different to http://website.com etc

Comment: I'm currently using http://faceconn.com/ to do fconnect. The URL I've configured on this resolves at a domain with a port number and works with firefox.  The url I have on app settings on facebook dev is also configured with the same url with a port number. This does not work on ie9. When I remove the port number it works on ie9 but not on firefox :)

Comment: In fact I guess it will be the same with the facebook php-sdk.

Comment: Ah got it to work.. I just put example.com (my domain i.e.) without the port number or subdomain in the app settings and its working on both browsers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ive clarified the answer as an answer to the post.  Feel free to accept as answer for people's future reference.  Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the URL for the app is exactly how it is shown in the browser.

`Http://www.example.com` is different to `http://example.com`

Also I don't think that you need to include your port number for it to work.

Comment: I had to *add* the port number, then once I did that, it worked and I could remove it once that change propagated.  Strange.  Anyway, if you're stumped, try adding the port number.